# add TableFooter view with StoryBoard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I want to add Table Footer view in storyboard. It works fine to display but footer view takes lots of height automatically.

**My Table position**

[image]

**My Table footer view with space**

[image]

**Help me to solve this**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the height of the footer view in the Size inspector on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change the Section Height for Footer of your tableview directly from your storyboard ?

[image]

Hope this'll help!